NPM workspace share Jest manual mock
Overview
I have an NPM package that uses NPM workspaces and contains four workspaces or packages. Each of these depends on some external dependencies, as well as there is some inter-package dependency as well.
The issue is that for some of my unit tests, they need to mock some of the external dependencies and I currently have a __mocks__ directory in each package but some of these mocks are duplicated between packages.
What I would like to do is to have the __mocks__ directory at the very top of the package, next to the overall node_modules directory but when I do that, the TypeScript compiler cannot find the mocks in the parent __mocks__ directory. Here is a rough example of my package structure:
├── __mocks__  <-- how could this be referenced from each package (p1 .. p4)?
│   └── **/*.ts
├── packages
│   ├── p1
│   │    ├── src
│   │    │   └── **/*.ts
│   │    ├── tsconfig.json
│   │    └── package.js
│   ├── p2
│   │    ├── src
│   │    │   └── **/*.ts
│   │    ├── tsconfig.json
│   │    └── package.js
│   ├── p3
│   │    ├── src
│   │    │   └── **/*.ts
│   │    ├── tsconfig.json
│   │    └── package.js
│   ├── p4
│   │    ├── src
│   │    │   └── **/*.ts
│   │    ├── tsconfig.json
│   │    └── package.js
├── package.json
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── jest.config.js
└── tsconfig.json

--
Attempts
Attempt 1
I have tried to update the tsconfig.json in each package to point the include property to the parent __mocks__ directory, but that didn't work. Here is what the include property looks like in the tsconfig.json file in each package:
"include": [
  "../../__mocks__/**/*.ts",
  "src/**/*.ts"
]

And here is the error that was received due to the __mocks__ directory being outside of this package:

cmd: 'tsc --outDir build/ES6/ESNext/src --declarationDir build/declarations/src --target ESNext --module ES6',
stdout: "error TS6059: File '~/MyProject/mocks/external-dependency.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '~/MyProject/packages/p1/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.\n" +
'  The file is in the program because:\n' +
"    Matched by include pattern '../../mocks/**/*.ts' in '~/MyProject/packages/p1/tsconfig.json'\n"

Attempt 2
I have also tried referencing this directory from the top-level tsconfig.json and then inheriting it in the individual tsconfig.json in each package, but the include property is overridden when extending a parent tsconfig file. Even if it wasn't there is still the issue of the __mocks__ directory not being in each package.
Question
How can I have manual mocks like this that are able to be used by multiple packages? Can I share these mocks or do they have to be repeated in each package?
Alternatively, is it possible to have another package (p5) that just exports these mocks and then the other packages here take a dependency on that? Would that work?
